# Handling JSON response which sometimes doesn't have array

Tags: c#, json

I am consuming some JSON in a C# console application and for some of the data, there is an array of options. Example JSON:

```
{
    "FIELD_NAME": "Survey",
    "VALUE": "",
    "FIELD_ID": 1234,
    "OPTIONS":[
        { "VALUE": "GENERAL", "DISPLAY_ORDER": 1, "DISPLAY": "GENERAL" },
        { "VALUE": "HPEFS",   "DISPLAY_ORDER": 3, "DISPLAY": "HPEFS" },
        { "VALUE": "NONE",    "DISPLAY_ORDER": 3, "DISPLAY": "NONE" }]
}
```

But sometimes for records in the JSON the OPTIONS is empty:

```
{"FIELD_NAME":"Product_Node3","VALUE":"","FIELD_ID":1740,"OPTIONS":{}}
```

As you can see the options is set to {} but it is my understanding that {} is an empty object, not an empty array.

When I try deserialize to a POCO I get an exception complaining that it requires a JSON array in the OPTIONS property.

My field class:

```
public class Field
{
    public string FIELD_NAME { get; set; }
    public string VALUE { get; set; }
    public int FIELD_ID { get; set; }
    public List<Option> OPTIONS { get; set;
    }
}
```

And options class:

```
public class Option
{
    public string VALUE { get; set; }
    public int DISPLAY_ORDER { get; set; }
    public string DISPLAY { get; set; }
}
```

The code which causes this exception is:

```
            var stringTest = File.ReadAllText("json.txt");
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Field>>(stringTest);
```

Exception is:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[testproj.Option]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

Comment: I believe this is fine with json.net so I would recommend using that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON deserialization fails only when array is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027041/json-deserialization-fails-only-when-array-is-empty)

Comment: @mjwills - not quite a duplicate.  In that question (as well as [*How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182)) the OP wants to deserialize the object as a one-item collection containing that object.  Here I believe OP wants to **entirely skip** the object.  I could be wrong though, so could OP please confirm?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @dbc .

Answer (score 1):

Json.NET will throw an exception when the expected JSON value type (array, collection or primitive) does not match the observed value type.  Since, in the case of your `List<Option> OPTIONS`, you want unexpected value types to be skipped, you will need to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) such as the following:

```
public class TolerantCollectionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.IsPrimitive || objectType == typeof(string) || objectType.IsArray)
            return false;
        return objectType.GetCollectionItemTypes().Count() == 1;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            existingValue = existingValue ?? serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
            serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);
            return existingValue;
        }
        else
        {
            reader.Skip();
            return existingValue;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return all interfaces implemented by the incoming type as well as the type itself if it is an interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (type.IsInterface)
            return new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces());
        else
            return type.GetInterfaces();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetCollectionItemTypes(this Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfacesAndSelf())
        {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
            {
                yield return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply it to `Field` as follows:

```
public class Field
{
    public string FIELD_NAME { get; set; }
    public string VALUE { get; set; }
    public int FIELD_ID { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(TolerantCollectionConverter))]
    public List<Option> OPTIONS { get; set; }
}
```

Or use it for all collections via [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new TolerantCollectionConverter() },
};
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Field>(stringTest, settings);
```

Notes:

- The converter only works for collections that are writable, since it allocates the collection first and then populates it.  For read-only collections or arrays you need to populate a `List<T>` first then allocate the read-only collection or array from it.
- My assumption here is that you want to **ignore** an empty object when an array value is expected.  If instead you want to **deserialize the object into a collection item then add that to the returned collection** you could use `SingleOrArrayConverter<T>` from [*How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182).
- The root JSON container shown in your question is an object -- an unordered set of name/value pairs that begins with `{` and ends with `}` -- rather than an array.  Thus you need to deserialize it as a `Field` not a `List<Field>`.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cgejq8).