# How to handle with Newtonsoft JSON that I get back empty list in wrong format from external API?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this class:

```
  public class Result
    {
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public string LeagueName { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string RegionName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string SportName { get; set; }
        public bool IsPreMatch { get; set; }
        public int SportId { get; set; }
        public string AwayTeam { get; set; }
        public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public int LeagueId { get; set; }
        public int? BetRadarId { get; set; }
        public List<Market> Markets { get; set; }
        public int our_event_id { get; set; }
    }
```

But when the Market is empty, the API I depend on returns `"Markets" : {}` instead of `"Markets": []` so it can't be deserialized. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is pretty common. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` should handle this on its own. What Json.Net version are you using? Can you show your deserialization method?

Comment: Looks like API should be fixed. Btw, here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25148172/12888024)

Comment: You can apply `[JsonConverter(typeof(TolerantCollectionConverter))]` to `public List<Market> Markets { get; set; }`, where `TolerantCollectionConverter` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47318382/3744182) to [Handling JSON response which sometimes doesn't have array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47317792/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Yes that works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/sUuNGT.